# fixing list out of range

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to extract a column from a file in order to put it in dictionnary then transform it to a dataframe, I've tried this code but It didn't work :

```
filename ="C:\\Users\Amin Chaari\Desktop\drugs.csv"

with open (filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
datas = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')

lines = [row for row in datas]
R={}
for i in range(0,5):
 print(lines[0][i])
 if lines[0][i] != 'userID':
    if lines[0][i] !='drugName':
        grouped_column = []
        for j,row in enumerate(lines):
            if j>0:
                grouped_column.append(row[i])
                R.update({lines[0][i]:grouped_column})
print(R)
df3=pd.DataFrame(R)
```

this is the error that I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-116-d9d691dce427>", line 9, in <module>
grouped_column.append(row[i])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

could you please help me ! Thanks

Comment: The message should be self-explanatory, your line (`row` variable) appears to be not long enough. What is the output of `print(row)`, placed before the line that causes the error? What is `lines` and where does it come from, what are its contents?

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to "fix" that would be:

```
R = {}
for i in range(0, 5):
  print(lines[0][i])
  if lines[0][i] != 'userID':
    if lines[0][i] !='drugName':
      grouped_column = []
      for j, row in enumerate(lines):
        try:
          if j > 0:
            grouped_column.append(row[i])
            R.update({lines[0][i]:grouped_column})
        except IndexError:
          pass

print(R)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(R)
```

This is more like a workaround into your problem than a solution. You should debug and see what's wrong. But the problem is your `row[i]` do not exists, would be better if you post  the entire code here or the values from lines.

## EDIT

This code will compare and check if the row contains the size needed to use, case not will ignore that part:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

FILE = "drugs.csv"

def main():

  with open (FILE, encoding="utf8") as f:
    datas = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    lines = [row for row in datas]

  R = {}

  for i in range(len(lines[0])):
    if lines[0][i] != 'userID' and lines[0][i] !='drugName':
      grouped_column = []

      for j, row in enumerate(lines):
        if j > 0 and len(row) > i:
          grouped_column.append(row[i])
          R.update({lines[0][i]:grouped_column})

  df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(R, orient="index")
  df3.transpose()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: I already reposted the entire code, you can check above. Thank you for the answer

Comment: Could you share your csv?

Comment: of course here is the link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ojc68TzYJ2wsC6mzeEyq4_i4vqU6rE9Z

Comment: Just a update, the problem is sometimes your data do not exists, so a made an edit in my post :)